# preg_match_all regex issue for url routing

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

for an url routing I have

Patern :

`/^\/stuff\/other-stuff\/(?:([^\/]\+?))$/i`

Subject :

`/stuff/other-stuff/foo-AB123456.html`

why $num_matches is equal to 0 ??

`$num_matches = preg_match_all($patern, $subject, $matches);`

Help should be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What is `[^\/]\+?` supposed to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of this:

```
[^\/]\+?
```

firstly there is no slash after `other-stuff` so you cannot find the sentence with a negated `/` secondly the `+` must not be escaped if you are doing this kind of match . `+` must only be escaped when you are doing a literal match.

the corrected regex should be :

```
^\/stuff\/other-stuff\/(?:(.+?))$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/aV9cR0

will match `foo-AB123456.html` in the first capture

Comment: `the + must not be escaped if you are doing this kind of match . + must only be escaped when you are doing a literal match.`

=> this is actually the main cause, thank you very much !

Comment: (top comment edited, I'm not used to post on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Littlekisscool i am glad it helped you :) you can accept the answer whenever time allows

Answer (score 0):

```
$patern= "#^/stuff/other-stuff/([^/]+)$#i";


$subject = "/stuff/other-stuff/foo-AB123456.html";


preg_match_all($patern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your regex could be simplified to something like:

```
(?i)^/stuff/other-stuff/[\w-.]+$
```

It would work like this:

```
<?php
$regex="~(?i)^/stuff/other-stuff/([\w-./]+)$~";
$string = "/stuff/other-stuff/foo-AB123456.html";
$hit = preg_match($regex,$string,$m);
echo $m[0]."<br />";
echo $m[1]."<br />";
?>
```

**Output:**

```
/stuff/other-stuff/foo-AB123456.html
foo-AB123456.html
```

Note that this could be done in a number of different ways.

Here are some details about the regex.

1. The `~` delimiter is nicer than the original `/` because you don't have to escape the slashes.
2. The parentheses in `([\w-.]+)` capture the end of the url into Group 1. This is why `$m[1]` yields `foo-AB123456.html`
3. After the final slash, `[\w-./]+` matches any number of letters or digits, underscores, dashes, dots and forward slashes. This is a "mini-spec" for what characters we expect there. If you want to allow anything at all, you could go with a simple dot.